# Using JavaScript and Greasemonkey to reload just one tab in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, javascript, greasemonkey

I am new to Greasemonkey and javascript but have found the script below to reload a page every 5 minutes.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Auto Reload Protopage
// @namespace   http://blog.monstuff.com/archives/cat_greasemonkey.html
// @description Reload pages every 5 minutes
// @include     http://ww.bbc.co.uk
    // @grant               none
// ==/UserScript==

// based on code by Julien Couvreur
// and included here with his gracious permission

var numMinutes = 5;
window.setTimeout("document.location.reload();", numMinutes*60*1000);
```

This works but it reloads all the open tabs every 5 minutes and not just the one specified in the @include statement.

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: [http://ww.bbc.co.uk](http://ww.bbc.co.uk) doesn't exist?

Comment: Sorry - that was just a typo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That code has a corrupt [metadata block](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block), spaces are critical for that block, and extra spaces at the beginning of a line can break it -- causing the script to fire for all pages (the default behavior).

**Update:**  The appearance of a corrupt block may just be a display bug here at SuperUser.  Will investigate in a bit.
**Updatier:** The corrupt block is real, the OP's code is indented by a mix of tabs and spaces, which fooled SU's raw-post editor, but not the final display.

Also, the `@include` directive is specifying a webpage that doesn't exist. `ww.`, versus `www.`.  That line should be:

```
// @include     http://www.bbc.co.uk/
```

Or possibly:

```
// @include     http://www.bbc.co.uk/*
```

if you want more than just the home page effected.

Putting it all together and using `setTimeout` in the recommended way (Avoid use of "auto eval()"):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Auto Reload Protopage
// @namespace   http://blog.monstuff.com/archives/cat_greasemonkey.html
// @description Reload pages every 5 minutes
// @include     http://www.bbc.co.uk/
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

// based on code by Julien Couvreur
// and included here with his gracious permission

var numMinutes = 5;
setTimeout (location.reload, numMinutes*60*1000);
```

Comment: Brilliant - many thanks for this. The script is now indeed only operating on the page I want rather than all pages.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how to do this in Javascript, but Firefox has an addon called [ReloadEvery](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/reloadevery/). Install it, restart FF and then right click on the page and choose ReloadEvery and a time.

Comment: Yes - but then every time I open Firefox and go to the website I need to activate ReloadEvery. What I would like is for the reload to be automatically activated just by going to the page. The javascript above does this but also reloads all other tabs that are open.